# Django update table using data from another table

Tags: django, django-orm, django-database

I have 2 tables `products` and `catagories` connected by foreign key.
I need to update field `products.new_cost` using field `catagories.price_markup` as following:

```
UPDATE products p
INNER JOIN categories c ON p.category_id = c.id
SET p.new_cost = ROUND(p.pleer_cost * (1 + c.price_markup/100), -1)
WHERE p.update = 1
```

In SQL it's so easy, but how to do it using Django ORM?

My simplified try doesn't work `Cannot resolve keyword 'category.price_markup' into field.`:

```
Product.actived.select_related('category').filter(update=1)).update(new_cost=F('pleer_cost') * F('category.price_markup'))
```

Answer (score 38):

You cannot use F, but you can use Subquery and OuterRef:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef

cost = Category.objects.filter(
    id=OuterRef('category_id')
).values_list(
    'price_markup'
)[:1]

Product.objects.update(
    new_cost=Subquery(cost)
)
```

Comment: As far as I got the idea of the relations between the two models, I would suggest the cost query filter to be like id=OuterRef('category_id')

Comment: just for the record, this is not possible in Django 1.7

Comment: What if the primary key is on the referenced table instead of the target?

Comment: @jbodily You can use like this
Product.objects.update(new_cost=Subquery(Category.objects.values_list('price_marup')[:1]))
But then all products will have the same new_cost

Answer (score 19):

### Note: My answer is outdated now, Django 1.11 [introduced](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) `OuterRef`  which implements this feature. Check Andrey Berenda answer.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once), updates using join clauses are not supported, see:

> However, unlike F() objects in filter and exclude clauses, you can’t
>   introduce joins when you use F() objects in an update – you can only
>   reference fields local to the model being updated. If you attempt to
>   introduce a join with an F() object, a FieldError will be raised:
>
> ```
> # THIS WILL RAISE A FieldError
> >>> Entry.objects.update(headline=F('blog__name'))
> ```

Also, according to this [issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14104), this is by design and there is no plans to change it in the near future:

> The actual issue here appears to be that joined F() clauses aren't
>   permitted in update() statements. This is by design; support for joins
>   in update() clauses was explicitly removed due to inherent
>   complications in supporting them in the general case.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the solution exists, see my answer below

Comment: @AndreyBerenda My answer predates Django 1.11, but I think it's still valid for people stuck with Django 1.11, I will edit the answer to point it to ours, thanks.

Comment: If you are on an older Django, then (a) you should upgrade, but (b) you can use the backport django-subquery: https://pypi.org/project/django-subquery/

Answer (score 0):

```
rows = Product.objects.filter(old_field__isnull=False)
for row in rows:
     row.new_field = row.old_field.subfield
Product.objects.bulk_update(rows, ['new_field'])
```