# Django bulk update with data two tables over

Tags: django, django-orm, django-database, django-database-functions

I want to bulk update a table with data two tables over. A solution has been given for the simpler case mentioned in the documentation of:

```
Entry.objects.update(headline=F('blog__name'))
```

For that solution, see

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50561753/1092940

Expanding from the example, imagine that `Entry` has a Foreign Key reference to `Blog` via a field named `blog`, and that `Blog` has a Foreign Key reference to `User` via a field named `author`. I want the equivalent of:

```
Entry.objects.update(author_name=F('blog__author__username'))
```

As in the prior solution, the solution is expected to employ `SubQuery` and `OuterRef`.

The reason I ask here is because I lack confidence where this problem starts to employ multiple `OuterRef`s, and confusion arises about which outer ref it refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The reason I ask here is because I lack confidence where this problem starts to employ multiple OuterRefs, and confusion arises about which outer ref it refers to.

It does *not* require multiple outer references, you can update with:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

author_name = Author.objects.filter(
    blogs__id=OuterRef('blog_id')
).values_list(
    'username'
)[:1]

Entry.objects.update(
    author_name=Subquery(author_name)
)
```

You here thus specify that you look for an `Author` with a related `Blog` with an `id` equal to the `blog_id` of the `Entry`.

Comment: The related name from `Author` back to `Blog` would more likely be `blogs` because an author can have multiple blogs. That said, I think I still might get this. Still chewing on it.

Comment: @AlanSE: If no `related_name` is specified, it is `blog__`, otherwise it is `related_name__id` (of course with `related_name` the related name).

Comment: All along I had assumed that nested `Subquery`s would be necessary. After much deeper investigation of my own problem (no longer a series of forward ForeignKeys), as well as your example, it turned out to not be necessary in any case. Thanks, this is resolved.